# C#/Dot-Net/.net library that does the same work as unix "file" command

Tags: c#, .net, classification

My google-fu is failed due to the common nature of the search criteria. I am looking for a c#/Dotnet library/class that does the same work as the unix "file" command. I'm trying to identify a collection of 3.5M files without extensions and classify them into images and sound files (mostly) and have as much info as possible afterwards.

Is there a wrapper class for the "file" functionality in the dot.net/mono space that anyone is aware of?

Comment: There are some suggestions in this Super User question - 

http://superuser.com/questions/272338/what-is-the-equivalent-to-the-linux-file-command-for-windows